# jQuery animate return to start state

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-animate, return

I need the second click function to return back (-=550px). As it is right now the graphic keeps on going.

Here's the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#busoptbio").hide();
    $("#current").click(function() {
    $("#busoptbio").show();
    $("#busoptbio").animate({left: '+=340px'}, 1200);
    return false;
    });

    $("#busoptbiolnk a").click(function(){
    $("#busoptbio").animate({left: '+=550px'}, 1200);
}, function() {
$("#busoptbio").animate({left: '-=550px'}, 1200);
    return false;
    });
    });
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#busoptbiolnk a").click(function(){
    var bio = $("#busoptbio");
    if(bio.hasClass('visible'))
        bio.removeClass('visible').animate({left: '-=550px'}, 1200);
    else
        bio.addClass('visible').animate({left: '+=550px'}, 1200);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that the second click do a back and forward move ?

if it's the problem try this

```
$("#busoptbiolnk a").click(function(){
    $("#busoptbio").animate({left: '-=550px'}, 1200);
});
```